# Data not getting stored in mysql using python mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, mqtt, mysql-python, paho

I am connecting to MySQL from my python script, subscribing to a topic from mqtt broker and whenever I receive the data I store the data.

code

```
import mysql.connector
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',database='db',user='',
                                   password='',auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')

sql_insert_query = """      #INSERT query
cursor = connection.cursor()

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    print("message received ")
    msg = json.loads(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
    #processing of message

    cursor.execute(sql_insert_query,processed_msg)
    connection.commit()
    print('inserted in db')

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc): 
    print("Subscribing to topic","topic")
    client.subscribe("topic")

broker_address=""
port = 8888

client = mqtt.Client(clean_session=True) #create new instance
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message #attach function to callback

print("connecting to broker")
client.connect(broker_address, port=port) #connect to broker
client.loop_forever() #stop the loop
```

So with this code saves the data when mqtt receives any message. But the there are times when mqtt doesn't receive data for more than 8 hours and then starts receiving data again.In such cases script is not storing the data which comes after 8 hours or so. I believe some kind of timeout is happening. Because when I re run the script again, data is stored in mysql db. Can someone help me understand what kind of timeout is this or how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You are connecting once at the top to database maybe connection has a timeout you connect to database each time a message comes and close when done in your `on_message` callback

Comment: Thanks!! any idea what could be the reason

Comment: Add a try/expect block round the database update code in the `on_message` callback. This will show you the error because the `on_message` function is called by the MQTT client in it's own try/expect block that discards all thrown execptions.

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting once at the top to database maybe connection has a timeout

You connect to database each time a message comes and close when done in your `on_message` callback

Reason : **Connection was getting timeout**

You can either set the timeout to higher time by

```
'SET GLOBAL connect_timeout=86400';
'SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=86400';
'SET GLOBAL interactive_timeout=86400';
```

Or simply instead of doing this you can do it in `on_message` callback

```
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',database='db',user='',
    cursor = connection.cursor()                                   
    print("message received ")
    msg = json.loads(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
    #processing of message

    cursor.execute(sql_insert_query,processed_msg)
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
    print('inserted in db')
```